# Как работает std::weak_ptr?

Tags: c++, smart-pointer

Если изначально `std::weak_ptr` указывал на нулевой указатель `std::shared_ptr`:

```
std::shared_ptr<Ptr> ptr = nullptr;
std::weak_ptr<Ptr> weak(ptr);
```

Но после этого `ptr` начал указывать на какой-то объект `Ptr`:

```
ptr = std::make_shared<Ptr>();
```

Указатель `weak` не изменить свое состояние и все равно останется `expired`?

```
weak.expired() == true?
```

Потому как следующий код:

```
int main()
{
   std::shared_ptr<Ptr> ptr = nullptr;
   std::weak_ptr<Ptr> weak(ptr);

   if (weak.expired())
   {
       std::cout << "shared is nullptr" << std::endl;
   }

   ptr = std::make_shared<Ptr>();
   std::shared_ptr<Ptr> ptr1 = weak.lock();
   std::cout << "counter must be 2. Actual: " << ptr.use_count() << 
   std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

В момент вывода в консоль количества владеющих указателей, мы имеем значение `1` при, как бы казалось ожидаемых `2`.

Получается, что `std::weak_ptr` показывает только актульную информацию про `std::shared_ptr` только на момент его создания? И если позже этот умный указатель будет изменен из не нулевого в существующий, `weak` указатель свое состояние уже не изменит?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

И `std::shared_ptr`, и `std::weak_ptr` прицепляются к общему "состоянию" ("блоку управления"), разделяемому между этими умными указателями. Состояние у `std::shared_ptr` появляется только тогда, когда появляется указуемый объект. Пустой `std::shared_ptr` не прицеплен ни к какому состоянию и никакого разделения состояния при присваивании пустого `std::shared_ptr` другому умному указателю (другому `std::shared_ptr` или `std::weak_ptr`) не происходит. При копировании пустых умных указателей они остаются пустыми и совершенно независимыми друг от друга.

Поэтому да, заметить переход `std::shared_ptr` из изначально пустого в непустое состояние другие указатели не могут. Ни другие `std::weak_ptr` не могут, ни другие `std::shared_ptr` не могут (ничего специфичного именно для `std::weak_ptr` тут нет)

```
int main()
{
   std::shared_ptr<std::string> ptr = nullptr;
   std::shared_ptr<std::string> ptr2(ptr);
   ptr = std::make_shared<std::string>("Hello World");
   std::cout << ptr.use_count() << " " << ptr2.use_count() << std::endl;
}

// Вывод
1 0
```